# Passing parameter to Controller Action from Kendo Window refresh in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have got a simple question: with a Kendo window, I can refresh it like this:

```
window.refresh({
    url: '@Url.Action("_EditScheduleInspectionForm", "TLM")',
```

I want to pass a parameter to that Controller Action. I tried the following and it works:

```
window.refresh({
    url: '@Url.Action("_EditScheduleInspectionForm", "TLM", new { test = "test"})',
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult _EditScheduleInspectionForm(string test)
```

The `test` variable comes filled with the passed string "test". But I don't want to hardcode the string, I want to pass a javascript variable there, like:

```
var test = "something";
window.refresh({
    url: '@Url.Action("_EditScheduleInspectionForm", "TLM", new { test = test})',
```

But the above doesn't work, the variable isn't recognized. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is going to be a string then you can always use replace to replace the static value with the variable value. Please see below:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("_EditScheduleInspectionForm", "TLM", new { test = "testvalue"})',,

var jsvariable = "something";

window.refresh({
url: url.replace("TLM",jsvariable ),
```

Or in a simpler way you can directly do it as below:

```
var test = "something";
window.refresh({
url: '@Url.Action("_EditScheduleInspectionForm", "TLM", new { test = ' + test +'})',
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't work but the above works fine. Although I must pass a dummy string to then replace, the resulting behaviour is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks